# Get data from MySQL with swift 3 and xCode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've searched for all possible guide, but xcode give me error with them code.

I need to do a php request in order to get data from a MySQL database, and then use that data with an UITable. I don't know how to da that.

Anyone could help me?

Comment: Try looking into `Alamofire`  ```let request = Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://testserver.com/form.php", parameters: parameters)```

Comment: can you provide some code?

Comment: serg_zhd I don't have code. I have only a php page that do a request to my DB, but I don't have problem with it. As soon as possible I'll look to Alamofire :) thanks

Comment: @Nathaniel I've successfully installed Alamofire (after 3 hours), and now i can do a request with it. Do you know how to parse JSON data? I've tried with SwiftyJSON but I can't install it (I've follow all methods on github but it give me error.)

Comment: @CarloDiDomenico If you use `Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://testserver.com/form.php", headers: header, encoding:.JSON).responseJSON { response in` , you can then use `if let data = response.result.value as? [String:AnyObject]`. Depending on how much data you have to process, you could simply do something like `var item1 = data["key"]`